Racket: expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
Im completely new to Racket and I got a homework to create a LL1 parser. From sample code, I tried to reproduce the code with some additional tests. My code looks OK to me, but the parser cannot run it. The code is below:
#lang racket

(define (is-number? str)
  (let ((maybe-number (string->number str)))
    (and maybe-number #t)))

(define (parse-expression expr)
  (define (parse-tokens expr)
    (define (parse-S exp)
      (cond
        [(empty? exp) #f]
        [(char-numeric? (car exp)) (parse-A (cdr exp))]
        [(equal? (car exp) "√") (parse-A (cddr exp))]
        [else #f]))
    
    (define (parse-A exp)
      (cond
        [(empty? exp) #t]
        [(char=? (car exp) #\+) (parse-S (cdr exp))]
        [(char=? (car exp) #\-) (parse-S (cdr exp))]
        [(char=? (car exp) #\*) (parse-S (cdr exp))]
        [(char=? (car exp) #\/) (parse-S (cdr exp))]
        [(char=? (car exp) #\^) (parse-S (cdr exp))]
        [(equal? (car exp) "√") (parse-S (cdr exp))]
        [else #f]))
    
    (let loop ([expr expr])
      (cond
        [(empty? expr) #t]
        [(char-whitespace? (car expr)) (loop (cdr expr))]
        [(parse-S expr) #t]
        [else #f])))
  
  (parse-tokens (string->list expr)))

(define (analyze-expression expr)
  (parse-expression expr))

(define (test-expressions)
  (define (run-tests tests)
    (for ([test tests])
      (define result (analyze-expression (first test)))
      (printf "Expression: ~a, Result: ~a\n" (first test) result)))
  
  (run-tests '("1" #t)
              ("1+1" #t)
              ("1 / 3" #t)
              (" √10 " #t)
              ("579438593 + 666 - 555" #t)
              ("1000" #t)
              ("2^64" #t)
              ("√2 + √64 * 233 + 6" #t)
              ("" #f)
              ("aaa" #f)
              ("/44" #f)
              ("579438593 +" #f)
              ("1000 * + 111" #f)
              ("2 + 6 4" #f)
              ("3.14 + 7" #f)
              ("√√2" #f)))

(test-expressions)

But the code dies on line 43, specifically ("1+1" #t) because I get an error
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: "1+1"

I might be doing something wrong, if someone could help me, i would really appreciate it.
Thanks!

You're missing a set of parens - how many arguments does your run-tests function take?

A list! Of course.. now the program works, but there is still an issue.. 1 / 3 returns #f, but shoudl have returned #t, but that is my problem.. Thank you!
